# X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing

Tags: angular, azure, header, content-type, x-content-type-options

I am developing a web application in angularjs5. The security team is testing our application and raised the bug.

Description: The Anti-MIME-Sniffing header X-Content-Type-Options was
not set to '`nosniff`'. This allows older versions of Internet Explorer
and Chrome to perform MIME-sniffing on the response body, potentially
causing the response body to be interpreted and displayed as a content
type other than the declared content type. Current (early 2014) and
legacy versions of Firefox will use the declared content type (if one
is set), rather than performing MIME-sniffing.

Url:
http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/dist/vendor.js?v=vBjTOpDNRC-nQNYd5TD5g6hxfdfdjc7SPrvBv0o2pPs

method:`Get`

Parameter:`X-Content-Type-Options`

Solution: Ensure that the
application/web server sets the Content-Type header appropriately, and
that it sets the X-Content-Type-Options header to '`nosniff`' for all
web pages.

If possible, ensure that the end user uses a standards-compliant and
the modern web browser that does not perform MIME-sniffing at all, or that
can be directed to the web application/web server to not perform
MIME-sniffing.

I have set header   'X-Content-Type-Options': '`nosniff`' in all HTTP requests as below.

```
 protected getRequestHeaders(): { headers: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; } } {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.appContextService.userToken}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': ` ${this.appContextService.subscriptionKey}`,
            'X-Frame-Options': 'Deny',
            'X-XSS-Protection': '1',
            'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
            'cache-control':'max-age=3153600'
        });
        return { headers: headers };
    }
```

Can someone help me to set header X-Content-Type-Options to dist/vendor.css,dist/main-client.jsdist/vendor.js? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I suppose this should be set in `apache` instead of `front end` side?

Comment: Thank you. We have hosted in Azure.